# Como acessar minha API de backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, back-end

Preciso acessar minha API de backend em node para que a mesma envie emails com informação de um formulário de contato.
Hospedei minha aplicação no King Host e aparece dessa forma [image: o endereço da minha aplicação está mais ou menos assim]
a questão é que, como sou meio novato no node, não sei acessar a minha aplicação remotamente para fazer o encaminhamento dos formulários ja tentei utilizar ambos os endereços com o nome da rota no final exemplo: `urldomeusite.com:num-porta/contato` e `urldomeusite.com/meusite/contato` e não funcionou...
esta é a minha requisição:

```js
const baseUrl = 'http://mywebsiteurl.com/contact'

const initialState = {
    message: {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        subject: '',
        main: ''
    },
}

export default class ContactUs extends Component {
    state = { ...initialState }

    reset = () =>{
        this.setState({message: initialState.message})
    }

    send = () => {

        const message = this.state.message
        const url = baseUrl
        console.log(message)
        axios.post(url, message)
            .then(this.reset())
            .then(alert('Message successfully sent!'))
    }
```

meu index.js (backend)

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const consign = require('consign')

const port = 4005

consign()
.then('./config/middlewares.js')
.then('./api')
.then('./config/routes.js')
.into(app)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(port)
})
```

Em middlewares.js eu faço a chamada ao cors

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')

module.exports = app => {
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(cors())
}
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar fico bastante agradecido!

Comment: Na verdade deveria funcionar sem porta alguma. Mas sem código é impossível ajudarmos amigo! Edita sua publicação com o código.

Comment: Ok, publicação editada! =)